# How to get order details for a Javascript tracking script?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I'm trying to put order id and value to tracking code but can't make it work. I tried to put there

```
$order_id = $order->get_id();
$order->get_id();
$order->get_total();
```

and nothing works. Here's code and places where I need these elements:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
tdconv('init', '2253741', {'element': 'iframe' });
tdconv('track', 'sale', {'transactionId':'ORDER ID HERE', 'ordervalue':ORDER VALUE HERE, 'currency':'PLN', 'event':400532});
</script>
```

Can anyone give me some tips?

Comment: Put more code. First thing on mind is `init`'s `{'element': 'iframe' }`. What iframe? :)

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' to be honest I'm not a developer, just shop administrator and I don't know much about technicals but that's a Tradedoubler tracking code on "thank you" page

Comment: Then better ask your developer :) Or consider implementing Google Tag Manager (tagmanager.google.com) or similar for easy tracking codes management without further code implementation requirements.

Comment: Related: [PHP calculate days from today for Google Survey Opt-In Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61944435/11987538), this is more or less the same, you can by example see how the order id is applied in javascript code.

Comment: @7uc1f3r that worked! thank you so much :)

Comment: @KubaA2A nice to hear, please consider reading [What is voting up?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) - Whenever you encounter a question, answer or comment that you feel is especially useful, vote it up!

Comment: @KubaA2A The below answer based on [*Tracking Add too cart & submit Order for Facebook Pixel In WooCommerce*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53892514/3730754) and  show you how to get order details on Order received page for your Javascript tracking code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to get order data for a javascript tracking script from order received page (thankyou):

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'thankyou_tracking_script_js' );
function thankyou_tracking_script_js(){
    // Order reveived / thankyou page
    if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) return;

    global $wp;

    // If order_id is defined
    if ( isset($wp->query_vars['order-received']) && absint($wp->query_vars['order-received']) > 0 ) :
    
    $order_id       = absint($wp->query_vars['order-received']); // The order ID
    $order          = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // The WC_Order object
    $transaction_id = empty($order->get_transaction_id()) ? $order_id : $order->get_transaction_id(); // The transaction ID
    
    ?>
    <script language="JavaScript">
    tdconv('init', '2253741', {'element': 'iframe' });
    tdconv('track', 'sale', {
        'transactionId' : '<?php echo $transaction_id; ?>', 
        'ordervalue'    : '<?php echo $order->get_total(); ?>', 
        'currency'      : '<?php echo $order->get_order_currency(); ?>', 
        'event'         : 400532
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related:

- [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)
- [Tracking Add too cart & submit Order for Facebook Pixel In WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53889578/tracking-add-too-cart-submit-order-for-facebook-pixel-in-woocommmerce/53892514#53892514)
- [Conditional Logic and custom FB Pixels Integration into WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53540447/conditional-logic-and-custom-fb-pixels-integration-into-woocommerce/53544527#53544527)